# In Visual Studios vb ,how does one maintain a panel or buttons smooth scaling or movement over time when its parent has a background image?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, timer

I would very much like to understand how is it that panels and buttons with png transparent  background images  can move through location.X and location.Y over time and /rescale without having to s update the parent background image in the transparent child button or  child panel control.

here is a code i use to make a mouse enter mouse leave sliding panel

```
       Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
            If entered = True Then
                Panel4.Width += 1
'or you can use Location.new point.......
    if Panel4.Width>= 100 then
    Panel4.Width = 100
    entered = false
    End If
            End If
            If exited = True Then   
                    Panel4.Width -= 1
    if Panel4.Width< 10 then
    Panel4.Width = 10
    End If

            End If

         Private Sub Panel4_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel4.MouseEnter
            exited = False
            entered = True
            Timer1.Start()

        End Sub

        Private Sub Panel4_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel4.MouseLeave
            entered = False
            exited = True
            Timer1.Start()

        End Sub
```

if the form has a background then each time the panel moves , it has to update its own background image with the background image of the form to give the illusion of being transparent , resulting in what looks like glitches in the sliding of the panel, correct ?

is there a way to get a smooth transition going ?

unfortunately a photo of the actual issue would be of no help

Comment: possible duplicate of [During FlowLayoutPanel scrolling, background distorts + flickers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341032/during-flowlayoutpanel-scrolling-background-distorts-flickers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the problem.  Are the "glitches" you mentioned, the flashing that takes place as it moves (actually, they just grow/shrink)?  Set the Form to `DoubleBuffered` will help a little, but you are redrawing the panel and form BG many, many times per second, so a longer Timer interval helps.